# How to use "SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement" on multiple columns specifically in MySQL database management system?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, distinct

I know how to use "SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement" on a single column as below :

```
SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Customers;
```

But what about using "SQL SELECT DISTINCT Statement" on multiple columns(PostalCode and Country are the two other desired columns) where I want different(i.e. DISTINCT) data elements from to each of the desired columns?

I want the answer specific to MySQL database.

I checked on stackoverflow. The questions like these have been already asked but the have been answered bt keeping in mind the MS SQL Server database. So, I've asked this question specifically oriented to MySQL database system.

Please provide me in detail solution with appropriate explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: Add sample table data, and the expected result. (`SELECT DISTINCT` works on the whole selected rows.)

Comment: **select distinct** always works across the entire row and results in ROWS that are different to every other row (regardless of where that difference is)

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT a,b,c FROM t

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
select distinct PostalCode ,Country 
from
yourtable
```

Note the Above distinct implies unique combination of `postalcode,country` not unique combination of  `postalcode` and unique combination of `country`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:
`SELECT DISTINCT(CONCAT(col1, col2, ...)) FROM Table;`
Or `SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM Table 1 group by 1, 2, ...`
Not sure which is performing better though.

Answer (score 0):

When you use distinct make sure the fields are selected only and has a redundant value like this:

```
Select  distinct fieldshas_duplicate_one,fieldshas_duplicate_two from table;
```